# How can I check what happens prior to and during computer sleep mode?

Tags: debian, suspend

My computer behaves strange when I'm putting it in sleep mode. There's roughly 50% chance that it won't enter sleep and will just keep waking up, despite me disabling all wakeup signals in `/proc/acpi/wakeup`. And after a while after waking up and sleeping it will sleep, but will start to heat up as if there's something resource-intensive program is working. I am using Debian Stretch and the computer is Macbook Air mid-2013.

How can I check what my computer is doing prior to and during sleep? Maybe that'll help to determine the source of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open up your terminal emulator and type in `sudo dmesg` prior to suspending to RAM, and make a note of the most recent timestamp. Then suspend to RAM. If your computer doesn't wake up on its own, resume and start from the beginning until it does wake up on its own. Check the output of `sudo dmesg` once more, then use your terminal emulator's search function (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) to find the timestamp from earlier. Start reading from there.